# Validating user input in C

Tags: c

So I need the user input for an int to be greater than 2.

```
    printf("Number of triangles (must be greater than 2) = ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &num_of_triangles);
    while (num_of_triangles < 3) // ?how to check using scanf?
    {
        printf("Number of triangles (must be greater than 2) = ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &num_of_triangles);
    }
```

Is there any possibility to optimize this code regarding the repeating lines?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please, post a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `while`, use `do`...`while`.  That way, the loop will always run at least once.

```
num_of_triangles = 0;
do {
    printf("Number of triangles (must be greater than 2) = ");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_triangles);
    while (getchar() != '\n');    // this flushes the input buffer
} while (num_of_triangles < 3);
```

Also, don't `fflush(stdin)`, as that's undefined behavior.

EDIT:

It seems that Visual Studio allows `fflush(stdin)`.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx):

> The fflush function flushes a stream. If the file associated with
>   stream is open for output, fflush writes to that file the contents of
>   the buffer associated with the stream. **If the stream is open for
>   input, fflush clears the contents of the buffer.** fflush negates the
>   effect of any prior call to ungetc against stream. Also, fflush(NULL)
>   flushes all streams opened for output. The stream remains open after
>   the call. fflush has no effect on an unbuffered stream.

In general however, this behavior shouldn't be depended on.  Doing something more portable like the above code is preferable.

Comment: We work in Visual Studio and our teacher recommended using fflush(stdin) before scanf(); . How should I replace this?

Comment: @Lorant Not initially.  Otherwise, `getchar()` will pick up the first value you enter instead of `scanf`.

Comment: The [MSDN page linked to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) has this comment in the example code: `// fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard`

Answer (score 1):

`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour, so you need to remove that entirely and substitute something else.

You should also check for the outputs of `scanf`, in case it fails.

If you want to improve readability, you can also move the `scanf` into your while loop directly, like this

```
while (scanf("%d",&num_of_triangles)==1 && num_of_triangles < 3)
```

Comment: The "undefined behaviour" claim needs some qualifications: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush (look for "Notes").

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code as this -

```
printf("Number of triangles (must be greater than 2) = ");

while (scanf("%d",&num_of_triangles)==1 && num_of_triangles < 3) //check return of scanf as well as number
{
    printf("Number of triangles (must be greater than 2) = ");       
}
```

Loop will iterate until `scanf` is successful and `num_of_triangles` is less than `3`.

Comment: Wouldn't while(scanf("%d", &num_of_triangles) != 1 || num_of_triangles < 3) be better?

Comment: @Lorant That will give you an infinite loop on character input.

Comment: @CoolGuy Sorry , but I don't get infinite loop with a character input .

Comment: Oh. I misread your code and got confused. It should be `while(scanf("%d", &num_of_triangles) != 1 || num_of_triangles < 3)` so that the error message is displayed on invalid input such as a character. You also need to clear the `stdin` in case of invalid input.

Comment: Why is it an infinite loop?

Comment: @Lorant If you enter a character `scanf` will return `0` so first condition is `true` and so due to `||`  , it won't check for second condition and loop iterate . Now , character remains in `stdin` and next time again `scanf` encounters that character and `return` `0` and so on . So it becomes an infinite cycle . You can remove character from `stdin` using `getchar()` though .